# Where is my database in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm creating my first project in (C#) ASP.NET MVC3 using Visual Studio 2010 Professional, I'm creating a very basic blog system. During the tests I created a some tables and now I want do store different data on those tables but I keep getting this error:

`The model backing the 'CategoryContext' context has changed since the database was   created. Either manually delete/update the database, or call Database.SetInitializer with an IDatabaseInitializer instance. For example, the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges strategy will automatically delete and recreate the database, and optionally seed it with new data.`

Obviously I need to update the tables in database but I can't find where I can access the tables. I can open Server Explorer using CTRL+ALT+S but there is no Database or tables there.

Here is the screenshot of it:

[image: screenshot]
http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/8944/screenshot001kd.png

Where/how can I find and/or edit the actual database tables?

Thanks.

Comment: did u look at App_data folder?

how is your connection string?

Comment: there is no App_data folder. Where is it meant to be?

Answer (score 1):

Well here is the best I can do for you:

If using SQL Compact Edition then you should look into your project folder on the filesystem and look for a folder called app_data and you should have a database in there.

Alternativly you could just open your web.config file and look for the section that is the "ConnectionStrings" section and just look for the location of the database.

If it is in SQL Server Express, then in your Database Explorer window, click on the database connections and create a connection to your local sql server express.  You should see it in the list of databases as the machinename\sqlexpress.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, I opened the database from App_data folder but the tables I created are not there. There seems to be only system tables.

Well, I will continue tomorrow because here it is 4:30 AM now... 
Thanks for answering Bipins and Jamie. Will see what can I do tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

From your error I'm going to guess that you're using Entity Framework's code first approach.

What happened is that Entity Framework has created a database for you on the local sql express install.  To find the actual database, look in your web.config file and find the connection string section which will tell  you the server and the catalog for the database. You can either us Visual Studio to access the database by using the data connection area found in the server explorer panel in your picture. Or you can use Sql Server Management Studio to do the same thing.

Now the reason why you're getting an error is because Entity Framework created that database based on the entities which you initially defined. Once you have made changes, the database no longer matches the entities and you get the error listed above. Your solution is to either delete your database once you have found it and allow the auto-magic to happen again, or you will need to do some changes to your code to not auto-generate your database each time you make scheme changes.

I would suggest you look through [MSDN's ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723) and read up on 'code first' development styles.

Good luck, and hope this helps you some.

Comment: Thanks @Chris
actually your comment helped to clear up quite some things in my head :)
ASP.NET for a beginner like  me, looks pretty much a mess up although it does not seem difficult once I get the basics ;)