# Database not showing up in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010

I'm developing an application using C# in Visual Studio. This is my first C# application which will use a local database and I am therefore unsure exactly how this is done.
I have been following [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19233/Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm) from codeguru.

I have declared my entities, all of which are currently just inheriting from this:

```
public class Reference
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ID of the reference.
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set;  }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reference to the element in theTVDB.
    /// </summary>
    public int TheTVDBId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether or not the reference has been marked as watched.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsWatched { get; set; }
}
```

I have also declared my DbContext as the following:

```
public class Library : DbContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor using the base constructor.
    /// This constructor names the database "Library".
    /// </summary>
    public Library() : base("Library")
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set of TVSeriesReferences stored in the database.
    /// </summary>
    public DbSet<TVSeriesReference> TVSeriesReferences { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set of SeasonReferences stored in the database.
    /// </summary>
    public DbSet<SeasonReference> SeasonReferences { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set of EpisodeReferences stored in the database.
    /// </summary>
    public DbSet<EpisodeReference> EpisodeReferences { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to store entities in the database doing the following:

```
Library db = new Library();

TVSeriesReference reference1 = new TVSeriesReference();
reference1.TheTVDBId = 1234;
reference1.IsWatched = true;
db.TVSeriesReferences.Add(reference1);

TVSeriesReference reference2 = new TVSeriesReference();
reference2.TheTVDBId = 8000;
db.TVSeriesReferences.Add(reference2);

int i = db.SaveChanges();
```

All of this seems to work. At least, I get no errors and `i` is 2 on every run.

The problem is that the database (which is named "Library") does not show up anywhere. Actually, I don't even have that "Object Explorer" view and I can't seem to find it.
As the database doesn't show up, I am unsure whether or not this is working and if my data is actually stored.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or if I am missing something?

Comment: From the View menu, choose Server Explorer. Your database should be in there. Or, do you see an EDMX file in Solution Explorer?

Comment: I don't see any database in Server Explorer or any EDMX file in Solution Explorer. This is all I see. http://cl.ly/image/1K2L3W3P2T1q

Comment: I'm going to come back to this, but I right now, I can't really help you, sorry. I have had this problem before so I will see if I saved any notes about it.

Comment: Actually, I just found this question. The answer at the bottom may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844137/where-is-my-database-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: I have tried the suggests in the answer but none of them seems to work. There is no app_data directory and even if I add my own Data Connection (which adds an .mdf file) there are no tables added to this database. Maybe I have missed some basic step. I'm not really sure as this is the first time I'm trying to create a database in a C# / Visual Studio project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have solved this problem.

I did the following:

1. In the Server Explorer, I right clicked the Data Connections, chose "Add Connection..." and created a Microsoft SQL Server. I set the server name to `.\SQLEXPRESS` and the database name to `Library`.
2. I then added the following to `app.config`:
   It seems to work now.

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Library"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Library;Trusted_Connection=true;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: It seemed to work but now [I'm struggling with another issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975374/code-first-with-the-entity-framework-throws-a-dbupdateexception). These two issues might be related but I'm not sure.