# Code First with the Entity Framework throws a DbUpdateException when saving

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I am trying to create my first database in a Visual Studio C# project and add an entity to this database. I have not yet managed to do so. When trying, I will get a `DbUpdateException` when calling `SaveChanges()` on the `DbContext`.

I am trying to save the following entity:

```
public class TVSeriesReference : Reference
{
}
```

`TVSeriesReference` does nothing but inherit `Reference`:

```
public class Reference
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ID of the reference.
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set;  }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reference to the element in theTVDB.
    /// </summary>
    public int TheTVDBId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether or not the reference has been marked as watched.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsWatched { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the following context:

```
public class Library : DbContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor using the base constructor.
    /// This constructor names the database "Library".
    /// </summary>
    public Library() : base("Library")
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set of TVSeriesReferences stored in the database.
    /// </summary>
    public DbSet<TVSeriesReference> TVSeriesReferences { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set of SeasonReferences stored in the database.
    /// </summary>
    public DbSet<SeasonReference> SeasonReferences { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set of EpisodeReferences stored in the database.
    /// </summary>
    public DbSet<EpisodeReference> EpisodeReferences { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I try to create and save the entity to the database.

```
using (var db = new Library())
{
    var reference = new TVSeriesReference
    {
        Id = 2,
        TheTVDBId = 1,
        IsWatched = true
     };

     db.TVSeriesReferences.Add(reference);

     try
     {
         db.SaveChanges();
     }
     catch (DbUpdateException e)
     {
         Debug.WriteLine("\n\n*** {0}\n\n", e.InnerException);
     }
 }
```

`db.SaveChanges()` will throw the following exception:

```
System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.TVSeriesReferences'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
```

I have been tearing my hair out for hours and hours now and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. It seems that the tables (or maybe the entire database?) is not being created.
Is there something I should have set up or have installed before this will work? I have installed NuGet and through that the Entity Framework.

Is there anyone who can help me get this to work?

**UPDATE**: ConnectionStrings in `app.config`

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Library"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Well the exception is clearly saying that there is no 'dbo.TVSeriesReferences' object in the database (I believe this is where you are trying to make update).

Comment: But isn't the Entity Framework supposed to create the database as well as the necessary tables? If not, can you tell me how I should create this? The goal is to store the data locally and it should only be available to this application (that's not a requirement though, I just believe that will be the most simple).

Comment: Prior to this code, have you initialized your database yet?

Comment: Well it depends. If you have set your connection string at an existing database then EF code first will not try and create one automatically. So what is your connection string?

Comment: @IronMan84 No. I have followed various tutorials on this subject and I don't believe that any of them has mentioned anything about initializing the database. Can you elaborate on how to do this? I just tried adding `db.Database.Initialize(true);` in the beginning of the `using (var db = new Library()) { ... }` block and it does not seem to do anything.

Comment: @tpeczek I have not added a connection string to `app.config`. Should I do this if I want the entity framework to take care of the database as well as the tables? If so, do you know what this connection strin should be?

Comment: Well you need a connection string to some kind of database... As you want to keep data locally SQL Server CE might be a good idea. Please read following blog post (it is ASP.NET related but you should get the idea): http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Comment: @tpeczek I have added a connection string as the one you see in the above question. Now it seems to work. At least it no exceptions are thrown and the data seem to be persisted. Do you know if that connection string seems reasonable? On a side note, do you know what information to enter when adding a data connection if I want to connect to the database using the connection string in the answer? Thank you for your help. Maybe you should leave your comment as an answer?

Comment: Well this connection string will work, but you should be aware that this will result in creating a physical file, you might want to give there some more meanigfull name, for example: connectionString="Data Source=MyDataBase.sdf". You shoudl try and experiment with this, I will put this all into answer once I'm back at PC as I have to go off now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While working with Entity Framework *Code First* you still need to set proper ConnectionString in your `app.config` file. For example if you want to have a local database in file, you can use embedded SQL Server CE 4 database engine (of course *Code First* can be used with many different databases including SQL Server, SQL Server Express and MySQL):

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="Library" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|CodeFirst.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/> 
</connectionStrings>
```

At run time, the `DataDirectory` substitution string is replaced with the appropriate directory path for the application's current execution environment. Without the `DataDirectory` substitution string, your application would have to programmatically determine the location of the database file based on the current execution environment and then dynamically build the path used in the connection string.

The *Code First* has also an auto-recreate functionality which is controlled by initialization strategy. The default initialization strategy is [CreateDatabaseIfNotExists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679221%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). With this strategy if your ConnectionString is pointing to database which doesn't exists *Code First* will create the database for you, but if the database already exists *Code First* will not try to create it.

The initialization strategy can be changed with `Database.SetInitializer()` method to one of the following:

- [DropCreateDatabaseAlways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679506%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)
- [DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679604%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)
- [MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

You need to remember here, that recreating database will lead to losing all data that were stored there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a database initializer and then initialize the database. Probably the best one to start off with, since this is a new database, is the DropCreateDatabaseAlways one. You can do the following:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Library>());
using(var db = new Library())
{
  db.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

Putting a connection string in the App.config, like @tpeczek said, would also be a good idea to do with this.

Comment: EF sets a default initializer of CreateDatabaseIfNotExists. You don't need to set the initializer unless you want to change it. And even then it would be better to consider using Migrations.